# ajax call timeout with 502 error

Tags: ajax, timeout

We have a report where it will pull data from server with jQuery ajax call, since data growing, server taking long time to return the data but after 30secs request getting timeout  with 502 error. Kindly let me know alternatives to get data in 1-5mins without getting timeout.

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

502's are usually thrown server-side, i.e. the server, or something in-between such as a proxy, is temporarily overloaded.

Not usually something that is controllable on the clientside (apart from retrying, but that's usually not the best option)

Is there a timeout on the server itself?

Comment: No there is no timeouts from server end, server returning data in 1min but by then that request getting timeout..

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"data.php",
    data:dataString,
    timeout:5000,
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    },

});
```

Note: timeout:5000,

Comment: Even if I put timeout as 1min in ajax, the request getting timeout at 30secs itself.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.